# (The) existence of a solution, (the) uniqueness of the solution

Tags: articles, mathematics

I want to write a sentence like

We consider the equation f(x)=0. We show that (the) existence of (a) solution and (the) uniqueness of (the) solution.

I want to know if the above sentence uses correctly "the" and "a".
In particular, I don't know if I should put "the" in front of "existence" or "uniqueness".

Answer (score 1):

In your given sentence,....

> We consider the equation f(x)=0. We show that (the) existence of (a) solution and (the) uniqueness of (the) solution.

...the word 'that' seems to make the sentence uncoordinated (assuming `We show that (the) existence of (a) solution and (the) uniqueness of (the) solution` isn't just part of a bigger sentence). Without the word 'that' and shortening the second clause of the second sentence, it becomes:

> We consider the equation f(x)=0. We show the existence of a solution and it's uniqueness.

....which I believe is more readable. I've maintained the use of the word `we` in case there's a scientific style of writing you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

Without context, it's difficult to recommend the best way to write these sentences..

Here is one approach -

> Consider the equation f(x)=0. This shows both (the) existence of (a) solution and (the) uniqueness of (this) solution.

My reasoning: I don't see any added value to using *'we.'* It's confusing in this usage and distracts us from the main point.

The sentences are focused on the equation, and that's how I've written everything - focusing on that.

Then, we're pointing out how the solution is other key part of what's being discussed. So, everything else is done to support this.